# Android studio RecyclerView question with videos

Tags: android-studio

I have a question I'm trying to build a Android app and i need help with something i'm to build a post recycler view with videos.

My question should i save the video url into a SharedPreferences or request the videos url every time the app opens.

Right now I'm using this code.

`RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(requireActivity());

```
     JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, response -> {

         if (response !=null){

             main_loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
             mAdapter = new posts_adapter(movieList,HomeFragment.this);
             post_revyview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


             for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                 try {
                     JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject(i);


                     String feed_image = data.getString("feed_image");
                     String feed_video = data.getString("feed_video");



                     posts_data movie = new posts_data(id,feed_video);
                     movieList.add(movie);


                 } catch (JSONException e) {
                     main_loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                     Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 }


                 LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
                 post_revyview.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                 post_revyview.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                 post_revyview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                 post_revyview.setItemViewCacheSize(20);
                 layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
                 layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);


             }

         }
     }, error -> {
         main_loader.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



     });
     queue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
```

`

Right now ever time the app opens the video has to reload.